# How to make discord bot wait for user response and log them into an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This is the code I wrote for it, but it seems to either loop without waiting for a response, or gets the response but doesn't save it to the array?

```
const pollOptions = ["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5", "Option 6", "Option 7", "Option 8", "Option 9"]

        for (var i = 0; i < pollOptions.length; i++) {
            await message.channel.send(`Enter poll ${pollOptions[i]}`).then(async o => {

                const filter = o.length > 0;

                message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, { max: 1, time: 30000, errors: ['time'] })
                .then(collected => {
                    message.channel.send(`${pollOptions[i]} set to ${o.content}`);
                })

                pollOptions[i] = o.content;
                return;
            })
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just say

```
let response = args.slice(1).join(" ");
```

that will take out the first argument and join the rest, That's a little suggestion at what you could do to help you.

Comment: hmm, I know that. I'm trying to make the bot delete the conversation after the final response and compile the responses into 1 embed. But so far i've only been able to do the latter

EDIT: Sorry, yeah i ditched the for loop and went with something else, lol I thought this was another question i posted